# Plotting a trapezium in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

How can I plot a figure in MATLAB such as a trapezium by giving only the vertices? I want the vertices connected by solid lines. I also want to calculate the area enclosed by the trapezium.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use fill(x,y,colour)

```
fill([1,2,3,4],[6,3,4,9],"red")
```

or plot(x,y) with the first elements repeated at the end:

```
plot([1,2,3,4,1],[6,3,4,9,6])
```

Edit: for the area

```
polyarea([1,2,3,4],[6,3,4,9])
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many options for plotting.

[plot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/plot.html), [fill](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fill.html), [patch](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/patch.html) would all be possibilities.

Use the function [polyarea](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/polyarea.html) to give you the area specified by a set of vertices.